# Honda Dylan 125 - dipped beam issue

Tags: honda, headlight, scooter

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Dipped beam turns on when the scooter is turned on. So it doesn’t seem to be a bulb or fuse issue. However, as soon as I start the ignition it turns off. When the engine is running the dipped beam doesn’t work, nor does the high beam - however the passing beam does work (which is the same as the high beam - so I don’t understand why the passing beam works but full high beam doesn’t). If anyone knows the answer then it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the dipped beam you are seeing. Many motorcycles/scooters have three lights:

- Pilot/parking: this is a low wattage bulb which turns on when the engine is off, it gives you enough light to push the bike to a spot without draining the battery, and makes you visible at night. In some bikes it acts as a backup to the low beam, but not always
- Low beam
- High beam

Sometimes these bulbs are individually replaceable, sometimes the functions are combined into fewer bulbs and other times they may be integrated as a single unit, you'll need to investigate how it is in your specific case. It sounds like you may have a combined low and high beam bulb which has blown or you have a bad electrical connection to it. I'd check the contacts for contamination and clean them before replacing the bulb.